# How to call a smart contract method with params with eztz?

Tags: smart-contracts, rpc, eztz

Does Eztz have some method for calling smart contract methods with parameters?

For example if my contract has a method

```
let%entry createFile ((fileHash : string),(manager:key_hash)) storage
```

How can I call this method from browser with Eztz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the contract send method:

```
eztz.contract.send(contract, keys, amount, parameter, fee, gasLimit, storageLimit)
```

For parameter, you just enter in the raw Michelson input (the same you would use via the tezos-client command). e.g. You could do:

```
eztz.contract.send(contract, keys, amount, '(Left (Pair "test" 1))', fee, gasLimit, storageLimit)
//For contract parameter (or (pair string int) (int))
```

For our specific contract, we need to know what the full liquidity and Michelson contract looks like as there can be multiple entry points which use the "or" method.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/CF3bByjE - my contract, how me call "createFile" entry point

Comment: Can you share the compiled Michelson code as well please

Comment: Stephen Andrews , https://pastebin.com/XYY7KuMt

Comment: You can use: '(Left (Pair "string" "tz1keyhash"))'

Comment: Sorry, but where i'm say which entry point use ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a readily available example for you but in eztz, contracts have a method `send` with a `parameter` parameter.

That should do the trick.

```
  send : function(contract, keys, amount, parameter, fee){
return eztz.rpc.sendOperation({
  "kind": "transaction",
  "amount": amount*100,
  "destination": contract,
  "parameters": eztz.utility.ml2tzjson(parameter)
}, keys, fee);
```